# Time Complexity: O(logN) or O(N)?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, analysis

I thought the time complexity of the following code is O(log N), but the answer says it's `O(N)`. I wonder why:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = N; i > 0; i /= 2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

For the inners for-loop, it runs for this many times: 
`N + N/2 + N/4 ...`

it seems to be `logN` to me. Please help me understand why here. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8... 1/2 ** n is a geometric sequence with a = 1, r = 1/2 (a is the first term, and r is the common ratio).

Its sum can be calculated using the following formula:

[image]

In this case, the limit of the sum is 2, so:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 ... = n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4...) -> n * 2
```

Thus the complicity is O(N)

Comment: Do you happen to know what is the order of growth of harmonic summation?

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding step by step, based on the code fragment, we obtain:

[image]